# I am working on json and getting the error returned a response status of 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, json

```
public class DSprojectClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String method = "N2";
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/EmployeeManage/demo/DS/" + method);
        EmployeeAddRequest addRequest = new EmployeeAddRequest();
        addRequest.setId(1103);

        String json = gson.toJson(addRequest/* , EmployeeAddRequest.class */);
        System.out.println(json);

        // String id = "1103";
        // String input = "{\"id\":\"1103\"}";
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, json);
        System.out.println("response" + response);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.toString();
        System.out.println("output\n" + output);
        EmployeeResponse addResponse = new EmployeeResponse();
        addResponse = gson.fromJson(output, EmployeeResponse.class);
        System.out.println(output);

        System.out.println(addResponse.getId() + ****************************");

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

This is the client code...

```
@Path("/DS")
public class Standardization {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/N2")
    public EmployeeResponse getDetails1(EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) throws Exception{
        DsUserService dsUserService = new DsUserService();
        System.out.println("getDetails1::object created");

        EmployeeResponse retval = dsUserService.AddEmp(employeeRequest.getId());
        return retval;
    }
}
```

this is the json code

```
public class DsUserService {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    static Connection conn = null;

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            DB_Connector.getInstance();
            System.out.println(" Connection made :: "+DB_Connector.connection);
            conn = DB_Connector.connection; // Get DB Connection
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public  EmployeeResponse  AddEmp(int id) throws Exception{
        EmployeeResponse retval = new EmployeeResponse();
        if ( conn != null ) {
            System.out.println(" DB Connection Successful ");

            String query = "Select name FROM harish_table_employee WHERE id="+id;

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                retval.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                retval.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

the one which hits db...

And the output is

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
    at com.infy.service.DSprojectClient.main(DSprojectClient.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
... 5 more
```

Please help me out here.. Whats going wrong?

Comment: You should check your line: `String output = response.toString();`. It seems that this does not return a JSON string, but something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to handle the objects directly without transformations in JSON. You can change the post parameter:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                                     .post(ClientResponse.class, json);
```

To send directly the object, and not the json, as:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                                     .post(ClientResponse.class, addRequest);
```

Alternatively, at your server side, you can add a service that takes a String as an input parameter:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/N2")
public EmployeeResponse getDetails2(String employeeRequestJson) throws Exception{
    DsUserService dsUserService = new DsUserService();
    System.out.println("getDetails1::object created");

    EmployeeRequest employeeRequest = gson.fromJson(employeeRequestJson, EmployeeRequest.class);

    EmployeeResponse retval = dsUserService.AddEmp(employeeRequest.getId());
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you. I am still getting the error and it goes like this...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.infy.service.EmployeeRequest, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Comment: @HarishDabade Do you want to accept this answer here in SO?